# Bloom and glow effects

Tags: canvas, graphics, three.js, webgl, shader

Giving some finishing touch to my particle system ([available here](http://marky.pl/vu/vf)), I wanted to add some nice visual effects, though could not find any good tutorials on them in the internet. Essentially I would like to add such bloom and glow to the particles like on this video -> [click](https://vimeo.com/56422121). This is can be probably obtained using shaders. Can someone give some hints, tricks, advice how to achieve an effect similair to the one I provided as example?

Comment: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_particles_shapes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particles usually aren't really blurred or with real glow effect, but rather use sprite image that has semi-transparent areas that are additively blended with all other particles. Particle simulation on the video attached uses that additive blend, and that could easily be done with Three.js, simply set material's `blending` param to `THREE.AdditiveBlending`.